# How can I create function templates for the two or more data types?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use function templates with two or more data types. So I made a example, which gets two 'T' type data then return 'T1' type data. Here is code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T, typename T2> T get(T2 a, T2 b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}

int main()
{
    cout << get<float, int>(10.2, 20.3);
}
```

I want that this code returns the larger of the two 'int-type' numbers to the 'float' type.
Namely I expected the result to '20.0'.  But the result is 20. I can not understand why the result's type is 'int'.
Please correct my code to return 'float' type, '20.0'.
Namely I wonder how to specify the data type of the return value if the input factor and return value are different.

Comment: You're explicitly telling the compiler that the second argument is an `int` when you call it.

Comment: Both `10.2` and `20.3` are coerced into `int` within the function, then as you `return` those (now) `int` are then coerced to `float` so you lost the `.3` in the process

Comment: also, `get(T2 a, T2 b)` should be `get(T a, T2 b)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can understand why the result's type is `int` . But I'm sorry that I can not know how can I set T to `float`.

Comment: This code is just to practice. I make this code to make function template which input parameter's type is `T` and return type is `T2`

Comment: I think I wrote the wrong question a little bit. I wonder how to specify the data type of the return value if the input factor and return value are different. I'm not good at English, please excuse me. Sorry

Comment: Your code is working correctly, is returning exactly `20` so `cout` doesn't print any decimal places

Comment: The new issue is output precision of cout. You could reproduce the issue in a short program:  https://ideone.com/CcXN73

Comment: I think if my code is working correctly for my purpose. It is returning `20.0` not `20` because I set return type to `float` (`T`)

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine, given the strange cast of inputs to `int`. Look at the output of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using namespace std;
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

template <typename T, typename T2> T get(T2 a, T2 b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}

int main()
{
  float test = 20.0;
  
  cout << get<float, int>(10.2, 20.3) << " "
       << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(get<float,int>(10.2,20.3))>().pretty_name() << endl;
  cout << test << endl;
}
```

which is

```
20 float
20
```

so, of course, the return type of your function IS float, the output is just how cout will show this to you. But you know, you can highly customize how cout prints out your data with `#include <iomanip>`.